# Help getting my route working for jQuery UI Tabs with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have my jQuery UI Tabs working right now but need help implementing the Ajax side. What I need help with is getting `#tab-2` to show information (`@user.messages`) from the `MessagesController` in a layout that's in `profile_messages.erb` in the `messages` view.

**My `application.js`:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**MessagesController:**

```
def profile_messages
    @question = Question.all(params[:user_id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xml {render :xml => @question}
    end
end
```

**My profile `show.html.erb`:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="infoContainer">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1"></a></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Messages", message_path(@message, :render => "false") %></a></li>
    <ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**My `profile_messages.erb`:**

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <% for 'message' in @user.messages %>
        <div class="message">
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

So how can I get `profile_messages` to load as a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get things working (almost!) due to loads of help here on SO. For some more code, check out this other question: [Exclude application layout in Rails 3 div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697317/exclude-application-layout-in-rails-3-div)